# javascript league api combinedTick callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
async run(message, args) {
    LolApi.init('censored', 'na');
    LolApi.setRateLimit(10, 500);
    var input = '';
    args = args.toLowerCase();
    LolApi.Summoner.getByName(args, function (err, summoner) {
        if (!err) {
            Name = summoner[args].name;
            Name = Name.toLowerCase();
            Id = summoner[Name].id;
            Level = summoner[Name].summonerLevel;

            input += "Name: " + summoner[Name].name + '\n' +
                "Level: " + Level + "\n";
            console.log(input);
            //message.reply(input);
            process.nextTick(LolApi.getLeagueData);
        }
        else {
            message.reply('Error fam.');
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){console.log('Waiting...')},2000);
    LolApi.getLeagueData(Id,'NA', function (err, summoner) {
        if (!err) {
            Tier = summoner[Id][0].tier;
            Division = summoner[Id][0].entries[0].division;
            input += "Tier: " + Tier + '\n' +
                "Division: " + Division;
            message.reply(input);
        } else {
            console.log(Name);
            console.log(err);
            message.reply('Error Fam' + Id + "test");
        }
    });
}
```

When i run this code up get an error 404 running the second part. It gives me an saying combinedTickCallback but im not sure what this means because i am a noob. I use node.js if that helps with anything

Comment: I'd guess that this line `process.nextTick(LolApi.getLeagueData);` gives you the 404. Please check out what `process.nextTick` does, because calling `LolApi.getLeagueData` like that makes no sense. Then, `setTimeout(function(){console.log('Waiting...')},2000);` is obsolete. `in 2 seconds print "Waiting..." to the command line`. I'm almost sure that this ain't what you meant. Next, why is this an async function? Did you remove some code from the snippet? And are all these variables defined or do you just pollute the global scope? Oh, and the second part has to be **inside** the first callback.

Comment: I ended up fixing it. I put the second part inside the first callback and remove the .nextTick. What im not sure though is what the .nexttick does. If you are willing to explain it to me that would be great!